# Laravel Livewire - How to force child component refresh

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'd like to refresh the child component when the parent is updated and only the child component of this component should update, because I'd like to reuse the child component somewhere else in the page. The components structure is the following.

`UserShow.php`

```
class UserShow extends Component
{
    public User $user;
    public int $userId;

    public function mount() {
        $this->user = User::first();
    }

    public function updatedUserId() {
        $this->user = User::find($this->userId);
    }

    public function render() {
        return view('livewire.user-show');
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <select wire:model="userId">
        <option value="1">Matteo</option>
        <option value="2">Giulia</option>
        <option value="3">Mattia</option>
    </select>

    <div>
        Name: {{ $user->name }}
        @livewire('user-show-email', ['user' => $user])
    </div>
</div>
```

`UserShowEmail.php`

```php
class UserShowEmail extends Component
{
    /** @var User */
    public $user;

    public function render() {
        return view('livewire.user-show-email');
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    Email: {{ $user->email }}
</div>
```

When the user in `UserShow` is changed via `updatedUserId()` method, I'd like that `$user` prop in `UserShowEmail` will change accordingly. By reading [the docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/nesting-components) it seems that Livewire is not able to automatically refresh the child component.

I wonder if there's a workaround, or something that allow me to refresh the child component when parent changed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you don't mind updating the whole child component, this would be one way of doing it:

> There's a trick that always work for me when I want to make a child
> Livewire component "reactive". In your parent livewire component you
> use a timestamp for the key attribute:
>
> `<livewire:child-component key="{{ now() }}" :my-prop="$myModel" />`
>
> The tricky part is the `now()` function in key prop. This component now
> will always be updated when the parent is updated.

In your parent component:

```
<div>
    ...

    <div>
        Name: {{ $user->name }}
        <livewire:user-show-email key="{{ now() }}" :user="$user" />
    </div>
</div>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/discussions/1895#discussioncomment-139040) and [here](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/discussions/2097).

Comment: Great! Thnks Remul, it works! Now I'm using the user ID as `key`, this way it should update the child component only when the user in the parent component is udated.

Comment: That seems hard to test. How do you test the child component?

Comment: Also it is useful to note, tat the component will be destroyed and mounted every time.

Comment: Depending on the case this could be useful or cause problems. I find my self using events to communicate changes instead of this solution.

Comment: @reppair how would you use events to update the content of a table? its not so easy. Say, if sorting changes

Comment: That's smartest one .

Comment: Can anyone please explain why this works?

Comment: @ABHi the key of the child element is set to the current time. Since when data is refreshed in the parent, the time changes therefore the key changes and thus triggers a re-render of the child component.

Comment: @Coola, I just got into livewire. Thanks for the comment, could you please tell me what key attribute for a component does?

Also how many other default attributes are there for a livewire component such like this.

Comment: @Coola Also, why did the key's value update trigger a re-render meanwhile other custom attributes we created didn't when their value got updated?

Comment: @ABHi I believe this is because other attributes a preceded with a `:` which makes them get parsed as php, while the `key` attribute is treated as html. Since it updates with the current time it gets ported to the front end.

Comment: @Coola if that is the case, will the custom attributes work if we didn't use `:` ?

Comment: You should try it but I don't think it will

Comment: it also works if you append `uniqid()` like so:
` @livewire('admin.question.show', [ 'question' => $question, 'index' => $index, 'slot' => $slot], key('slot-'.$slot->id.'-'.$question->id.'-'.uniqid()))`