# How to Pass data from livewire 2.x component to another?

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have two Livewire components **DeliveryFees.php** And **CheckoutPost.php**

*this is the code for the* **DeliveryFees.php**

```
public $deliveryFees ="0";
public function render()
{
    $cart = Cart::content();
    return view('livewire.delivery-fees',compact('cart'));
}
```

*this is the code for the* **CheckoutPost.php**

```
class CheckoutPost extends Component 
public fucntion render()
{
return view('livewire.checkout-post');
}
```

what I am trying to do is to pass the data value of **$deliveryFees** to the **CheckoutPost.php**
to render it inside the view `return view('livewire.checkout-post');`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Livewire - How to force child component refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65392402/laravel-livewire-how-to-force-child-component-refresh)

Comment: no it didn't am sorry !! can u suggest a solution based on what I have shown ?